# Parsing json in R: how to reference a node using a variable?

Tags: r, json

I am new to **R** and struggling with one particular issue.  I have called an endpoint and retrieved a deeply nested result.  I need to get a few values at the root level. I can do that no problem like this:

```
data_fromJson$id
```

This will correctly return the id of the post.

What I would like to do is create a function where I can pass in the name of the variable.  is this even possible?  For example, `variable_name` is the parameter in the function.

```
data_fromJson$<variable_name>
```

I can't convert to a tibble or dataframe without doing some other operations - the conversions complained about the data.  As noted earlier, I just need to grab a few values from the root.

Comment: It is just a list, so you could use the form `data_fromJson[[variable name]]` rather than the `$` notation